# Prestashop 1.7 - Duplicated emails in Customers Webservice

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

This is PS 1.7.4.4

In my prestashop I need to create customers using the webservice. It's working fine but also allows to create duplicated emails. This is an error.

I need to make email field unique. Maybe in classes/Customers.php but I'm totally new on this so I dont know how to make this change.
Please give me a hint

Answer (score 0):

We must first check if the email is already present, and if it is not ask the WS to create the client.

Codially,

Comment: I can't controll the app sending the data to the webservice, I need to add the validation in the webservice

Comment: Normally it is impossible to create two customer accounts with the same email! Otherwise it may be guest accounts that are created and not a client.

Comment: If I send this to the webservice X times I get X new users, all duplicated, no errors
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<customer>
<lastname>fioriaaa</lastname>
<firstname>agustinaaa</firstname>
<email>falso@mail.com</email>
<company>Clarika</company>
<active>1</active>
<note>este usuario se creó como parte de un test</note>
<is_guest>0</is_guest>
<id_shop>1</id_shop>
<id_shop_group>1</id_shop_group>
<passwd>123123123</passwd>
</customer>
  </prestashop>`

Comment: Hi : look here : https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues/17493